# Как использовать следование по редиректам (tornado python)

Tags: python, curl, tornado

Нужно что то подобное команде "`curl -L example.com`", но для python

```
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient

client = HTTPClient()

response = client .fetch("example.com", method='POST', body='')
```

Нужен наиболее простой способ встроить это в текущий код.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла ответ (пусть и костыльный) сама, может кому пригодится:

```
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient    
client = HTTPClient()

try:          
    response = client .fetch("example.com", method='POST', body='', follow_redirects=False)        
except Exception as resp:        
    pass           
response = client.fetch(resp.response.headers['Location'], method="POST", body='')
```

В итоге получаем, что после редиректа запрос аналогичный первому отправляется на новый домен, указанный в хэдэре 'Location', методом post (в первоначальном варианте вторая отправка шла методом get).